# Approaches to deployment in Continues Integration - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-delivery

I have a doubt regarding the best way to make the deployment of the artifacts of an application, I know i can create separate jobs to do this, but the  Deployment Job would have to build the application again, or have a way to enjoy the artifact generated by the build job?

Or the best way would be to join the Build and Deployment Jobs in one? Considering the flexibility of not having to make a deployment to each commit

PS: Internal Environments Deployments

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a general question, so I'll give you a general answer... you can basically store the artifacts in a shared location and have the deployment job take the latest one.
Alternatively, you can consider having a single build job with a parameter (e.g. 'Include_Deploy' = 0/1) so you have control whether the compilation will be followed by deployment or not.